# Why does Ojiro get angry from hearing the word "bakeratta"?

Tags: megane-x-parfait, obake-no-qtaro

When Misao is trying to find Ojiro, she tries to figure out who he is by being the only person who reacts to the word ***"bakeratta"***.

He gets very annoyed and because of this she's able to find him.

[image]

Why is Ojiro so offended by this word?

I looked it up a bit and found that it's a reference to [Obake no Q-Taro](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obake_no_Q-tar%C5%8D), but it still doesn't explain his anger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears one of the main characters of [Obake no Q-taro](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obake_no_Q-tar%C5%8D) is also called Ojiro.

I thought Q-taro was the one who said "Bakeratta", so I was looking mostly at his character - but it is actually his little brother, Ojiro, who is the link.

He can understand everyone speak, but can only say "Bakeratta", Q-taro is the only one who understands what this means.

---

So I guess his Ojiro and his brother (in *Megane X Parfait*) watched it before, and made a joke out of it because they share the name.